# Where is the lost dollar?

Tags: problem-solving

Somebody explained me this problem, but I am not sure to understand what is wrong.

```
Three people go to a bar to have a drink.
To pay the bill everyone gives $10.
The barman gives back $5 coins.
Every people take $1 back and leave the $2 other dollar for the barman.
```

If everybody give \$10 and get \$1 back, they paid \$9 right?

```
3 * $9 + $2 = $29
```

Where is the missing dollar?

Comment: if every people take $1$,then barman also take $1$  right? :D

Comment: Dat grammar wow

Comment: You are adding the 2 the barman got to the 27 they spent.  The 2 comes out of the 27 to get the 25 the bar got.  There is no reason to get anything sensible when you add 27 and 2 here.

Comment: @qwr I eventually fixed it but you could also have proposed to edit the question yourself. Tell me if you see something I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True $3*9=27$.

But they paid $25\$$ and gave $2 \$ $ tip. And

$$25+2=27=3*9 \,.$$

Comment: Of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[There is no missing dollar.](http://spikedmath.com/334.html)

\$30 - \$5 = \$25 paid to the barman.
\$2 tip + $3*\$1$ = remaining \$5.

Answer (score -1):

The math is simples:

1. 10*3 = 30 and 30-25 = 5
2. (1*3)+2= 5

∴

There is no loss.