# Simple Equation?

Tags: logic

You saw a T-shirt of sh  97, since you
don't have cash you borrow sh50 from
your dad and sh50 from your Mom.
Now you have sh100. You purchase a
T-shirt for sh97 and left with sh3.00
change. You return sh1 to your dad
and sh1 to your mom and keep the sh1
for yourself. Now you owe your mom
Sh49 and your dad sh49. Added
together(sh49+sh49=sh98) plus your
Sh1=sh99. Where is the missing sh1???

Comment: [Spiked math version](http://spikedmath.com/334.html)

Comment: Also see [Where is the lost dollar?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656047/where-is-the-lost-dollar)

Comment: The sweet shop has Sh3000; we compute sh49+sh49+sh3000=sh3099.  Where did the extra Sh2999 come from?  Answer: from adding quantities that are irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It was really eating my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your payable $\displaystyle (49+49)$sh $=98$sh

You have $1$sh $+$ T-shirt worth $97$sh

Comment: Accounting helps to get the balance

Comment: @AlexanderKimaru, Yes,(Payable(s) + Paid) & (Receivable(s) + Received)